# Is it possible to configure apache tomcat 9 with My Eclipse 2014

Tags: apache, tomcat, myeclipse

MyEclispse 2014 has the options to configure apache tomcat up till version 8. Is it possible to configure apache tomcat 9 with MyEclipse 2014?

Answer (score 1):

MyEclipse 2014 doesn't support that (Tomcat 9 wasn't available at the time) though I think there is an option to deploy to a particular folder, which you could specify as the Tomcat deployment folder, then start Tomcat external to MyEclipse. Right click on the project and go to MyEclipse->Add and Remove Deployments then press the Add button and select either Custom Location or Custom Location - Suffixed (the latter adds a ".war" suffix to the deployment folder name); this will then be available in the Servers view.

Tomcat 9 is, however, supported in the latest release of MyEclipse, so you can always upgrade to that, at no extra cost and get full server capability.